# Sort a column in Listview Vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, listview, columnsorting

Sorry i think this might be duplicate question. I think so. Well i have done datagrid columns and it was able to sort with the code below but i tried to to this for lisview but it dosent seem to work. I want to sort list view based on a button click not column click. Is this even possible? I tried This link from MSDN but i didnt understand it. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319399 So below here is my code for sorting datagridview. Is it posible to apply it for lisview? Integer i is a global variable.

```
     i += 1

    Dim x As Integer = grdDataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex

    If i Mod 2 = 1 Then
        'sort up
        grdDataGrid.Sort(grdDataGrid.Columns(x), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)

    ElseIf i Mod 2 = 0 Then
        'sort down
        grdDataGrid.Sort(grdDataGrid.Columns(x), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check the answer at the following post:

[Sorting A ListView By Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548312/sorting-a-listview-by-column)

They give you several examples, but they also recommend `ObjectListView`
who will make your job easier:

[A Much Easier to Use ListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx)