# sorting in listview using vb.net 2008?

Tags: vb.net, listview, sorting

how will I sort my data in listview using vb.net 2008 without using the listview1_columnclick ?

here's my code and it doesn't sort properly.

```
       If ListView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending Then
        ListView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending
       Else
        ListView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
       End If
```

many thanks for the reply.

-jane

Comment: double question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548312/sorting-a-listview-by-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the ListView how to do its sorting.

In C#:

Create a comparer:

```
// Implements the manual sorting of items by columns. 
class ListViewItemComparer : IComparer
{
    private int col;
    public ListViewItemComparer()
    {
        col = 0;
    }
    public ListViewItemComparer(int column)
    {
        col = column;
    }
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return String.Compare(((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[col].Text, ((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[col].Text);
    }
}
```

And then invoke the sorting by calling:

```
this.listView1.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer(colNum);
```

where *colNum* is the index of the column you want to sort.

Example taken from here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columnclick.aspx

And here's the solution in VB.net:

Create a comparer:

```
' Implements the manual sorting of items by columns. 
Class ListViewItemComparer
    Implements IComparer

    Private col As Integer 

    Public Sub New()
        col = 0
    End Sub 

    Public Sub New(ByVal column As Integer)
        col = column
    End Sub 

    Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) As Integer _
       Implements IComparer.Compare
        Return [String].Compare(CType(x, ListViewItem).SubItems(col).Text, CType(y, ListViewItem).SubItems(col).Text)
    End Function 
End Class
```

And then invoke the sorting by calling:

```
Me.listView1.ListViewItemSorter = New ListViewItemComparer(colNum)
```

where *colNum* is the index of the column you want to sort.

Comment: @RussellKeane Is it correct, that your ListViewItemComparer only works for columns with text content, not for numeric values or dates as content, right?

Comment: @PeterCo - In the example given above, yes. But you could quite easily change it to check the type of the value in the column (or a value looked up elsewhere if you wanted) and use the appropriate comparison method for that.

Comment: @PeterCo Or, if you had another type of value represented as text (say a date of "12th September 2016"), you could cast that to its proper type (using Date.Parse) and then use that for the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle ascending/descending, then you also need to track "sort order".  In both your comparer, and your column clicked event handler.

EXAMPLE:

**ListViewItemComparer.vb:**

```
Public Class ListViewItemComparer
    ...
    Private col As Integer
    Private order As SortOrder
    ...
    Public Sub New()
        col = 0
        order = SortOrder.Ascending
    ...
    Public Sub New(ByVal column As Integer, order As SortOrder)
       ...
    Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) As Integer Implements IComparer
        ...
        ' Perform "compare": -1: s1 < s2; 0: s1=s2, 1: s1 > s2
        Dim retval As Integer = -1
        retval = [String].Compare(CType(x, ListViewItem).SubItems(col).Text, CType(y, ListViewItem).SubItems(col).Text)

        ' Reverse if "descending"
        If order = SortOrder.Descending Then retval *= -1
```

**Form1.vb**

```
   Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      ...
      ' Allow "reverse" sort
      ' Initial order is "NONE".  As any column is clicked, the order will toggle between Ascending (first), then Descending
      ReDim ColumnOrder(4)
      For i As Integer = 0 To ColumnOrder.Length - 1
          ColumnOrder(i) = SortOrder.Descending
      Next
   ...
   Private Sub ListView1_ColumnClick(sender As Object, e As ColumnClickEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ColumnClick
      Dim ColumnHeader As System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader = ListView1.Columns(e.Column)
      If ColumnOrder(e.Column) = SortOrder.Descending Then
          ColumnOrder(e.Column) = SortOrder.Ascending
      Else
          ColumnOrder(e.Column) = SortOrder.Descending
      End If
      ListView1.Sorting = ColumnOrder(e.Column)
      ListView1.Sort()
      ListView1.ListViewItemSorter = New ListViewItemComparer(e.Column, ListView1.Sorting)
      ...
```

Look here for more details: [MSDN: Sorting ListView Items by Column Using Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996467.aspx)