# Sorting the whole ListView basing from a column automatically C#

Tags: c#, listview

I have tried several techniques online, but I really can't find any way to automatically sort the whole ListView, basing from a column.

Basically, I want the listview to be sorted without pressing any button, just when I open the form, it automatically gets sorted.

Here is what my listview looks like:
[my listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kz1Z.png)

The `Team Name, Wins, and Losses` columns, they were from a file that I wrote into the listview. But the `%` is the result from `wins / total games played`.

```
lvwTeams.View = View.Details;
lvwTeams.GridLines = true;
lvwTeams.FullRowSelect = true;

lvwTeams.Columns.Add("%", 60);
lvwTeams.Columns.Add("Team Name", 300);
lvwTeams.Columns.Add("Wins", 80);
lvwTeams.Columns.Add("Losses", 80);

List<string> teamLines = File.ReadAllLines(C:\\Data).ToList();

string[] arr = new string[6];
ListViewItem itm;

foreach (var line in teamLines)
{
    string[] entries = line.Split(',');

    int sum = int.Parse(entries[4]) + int.Parse(entries[5]);
    double percentage = double.Parse(entries[4]) / sum;

    arr[0] = percentage.ToString();
    arr[1] = entries[1];
    arr[2] = entries[4];
    arr[3] = entries[5];
    itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
    lvwTeams.Items.Add(itm);
}
```

I am really new in windows form file handling, please help

Comment: Could you copy and paste the C# code snippet that you wrote for your problem please?

Comment: For a flexible ListView sorting see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548312/sorting-a-listview-by-column/44469258?r=SearchResults&s=1|54.1754#44469258). You need to know which column to sort by, maybe the datatype and of course you to have data.. - Of course instead you can sort the data before adding the items.

Comment: I cannot sort the data first before writing into the file because it is strictly not allowed by our professor.

Comment: I am also using a .csv file btw

Comment: I'd create a class called `TeamStats` with the relevant properties. I'd create a `List<TeamStats>` and populate it with values from the .csv file. Then I'd sort that list and finally add the values to the `ListView`.